# Flexbox overflow scroll in angular component

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I am trying to build a two column design with an Angular 2 app. I created a plunker to reproduce my problem: https://plnkr.co/3Evxm9?p=info

I want the scrollable area to be the red div (`.overflow`), not the `.page`. Without the `.page { overflow: auto }` the page won't scroll at all, though I would expect `.overflow` to do so since it has a defined height of `100%`. The `padding` is there to offset from the `.top` div. I initially though using `margin` instead, but without the `overflow: auto` on `.page`, the margin goes outsides the bounds of `.container` (which shrinks to fit the height (padding included, margin excluded) of `.overflow`.

I seem to misunderstand the behaviour of the flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

I made some adjustment to your css to make the red area scrollable only.

css:

```
.page {
  width: 100%; height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 64px;
  height: 93vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Thanks for providing a plunker. It helped a lot to find a solution for you. Here's the [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/1lUuji?p=preview) to the edited plunker.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! The problem I have with your solution, which indeed works well, is that the scrollbar does not show for the correct area. It should only go up until the bottom of the blue area. I need the red area to fill exactly the remaining space of the screen below the blue area. I only see two approaches so far: (1) margin-top with the height of the blue area, and height of 100%; (2) `.page` with `display:flex`, column direction, and `.overflow` with flex one, but then we need additional nodes inside `.overflow` to perform the scroll. I'll upvote you :)